# Deleting a s3 directory from terminal is not getting reflected in metadata

Tags: shell, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a spark program and its output directory is in s3. When I delete the previous output directory from terminal using aws s3 rm --recursive  for next execution of spark program, an error is getting..com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.exception.ConsistencyException: Directory present in the metadata but not s3.
When I use emrfs sync command after deleting the directory, issue is not coming. but this command also fails sometimes.

Comment: Have you added EMRFS for the metadata or normal S3